# How to configure distributed caching in Grails (without Terracota)

Tags: grails, ehcache

I want to deploy my application (Grails 1.3.5) in two or more tomcats (7.0). I managed to do it without problems but now I want to configure my cache (ehcache) using RMI.

What I have done until now is creating two ehcache.xml and saved them in the lib folder of each tomcat.  Inside the ehcache files I declared 3 caches:

1. defaultCache
2. org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache
3. org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache

Each cache has a RMI replicator inside. This works well but my question is if I also have to declare each of my Grails domain classes inside the `ehcache.xml` file. If I do this I would have the same declaration twice: one in the `ehcache.xml` and the second in the class itself (I already set `cache=true` in the class);

```
class Book {
    static mapping = {
        ...
        cache true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need settings in both places. The `ehcache.xml` values configure the cache settings but they'll be ignored unless you enable caching for each domain class (and optionally mapped collections).

Ordinarily you wouldn't use the same settings in the `defaultCache` block though, since each domain class will typically need different settings, e.g.

```
<cache name='com.yourapp.SomeDomainClass'
       maxElementsInMemory='1000'
       eternal='true'
       maxElementsOnDisk='0'>

       <cacheEventListenerFactory
           class='net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory'
           properties='replicateAsynchronously=false
                       replicatePutsViaCopy=false,
                       replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false,
                       replicatePuts=true,
                       replicateUpdates=true,
                       replicateRemovals=true'
       />
</cache>
```

Comment: thank you very much for this answer Burt!. I was struggling with this problem for a long time.